# Unable to deploy .zip file using Kudu api to the Azure App Service

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, kudu

I'm using PowerShell inline task in the release pipeline to deploy the respective zip file to the Azure App Service, but im unable to achieve it due to the below error. Can you please let me know if there is any thing that im missing here.

I'm getting below error
Invoke-RestMethod : Path 'D:\a\r1\a_CI-VI-Maven/DeployPackages/marnet.zip' resolves to a directory. Specify a path including a file name, and then retry the command.

[image]

**Below is the script that im using:**

$username = "username"
$password = "pwd"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$apiUrl = "https://{appservice}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/webapps/"
$filePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)_CI-VI-Maven/DeployPackages/marnet.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

Comment: In local it works like a charm. I tried using the PUT method as well and still the same result persist.

Later I tried creating a sample project and did the same process, with no code changes, it works as expected.

I'm still figuring out the issue.

Comment: Check my answer below, you should correct the value of `$filepath` in your script, the `marnet.zip` is a folder name instead of a zip file, maybe the real file path is `path/marnet.zip/xx.zip`. Correct the path and your issue would go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your folder structure, it seems that you have a folder named `marnet.zip`!

Your issue occurred since the `$filePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)_CI-VI-Maven/DeployPackages/marnet.zip"` is a path to folder `marnet.zip` instead of a real `marnet.zip` file.

**My reproducible steps:**

1.Everything works well when my `s.zip` **file** locates directly under build artifacts folder.

2.Change something in Build pipeline to create `s.zip` folder, and move the `s.zip` file to this folder.

[image]

3.Then, same issue occurs:

[image]

Comment: It worked now, able to fix it now, thanks guys for the reply  @Krzysztof Madej

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)

```bsh
$username = "`$website"
$password = "pwd"
# Note that the $username here should look like `SomeUserName`, and **not** `SomeSite\SomeUserName`
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

# Example 1: call the zip controller API (which uses PUT)
$apiUrl = "https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"
$filePath = "C:\Temp\books.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"

# Example 2: call the zipdeploy API (which uses POST)
$apiUrl = "https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$filePath = "C:\Temp\books.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

So if you want to use zip controller API please change your verb to PUT insted of POST.

Comment: tried using PUT method as well, still the same issue.